# Php sql query working fine but as i use two condition in same join not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query worked well but want to add another condition in it but  it giving error  Not unique table/alias: 'users'

Here is my code

```
$query = 'select group_concat(DISTINCT evaluation_section. section_name) as   allowed_sections from evaluation_section 
            join section_permissions on (section_permissions.section_id = evaluation_section.section_id )
            join users on ( users.user_id = section_permissions.user_id )
            join users on ( users.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for )
            where  users.user_id = '.$user['user_id'];
```

want select name from users table also and then use this condition join users on `(users.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for )`

please help me

This is my edited text
this is my full working query

```
$q = 'select  group_concat(DISTINCT evaluation_section. section_name) as   allowed_sections from evaluation_section 
        join section_permissions on (section_permissions.section_id = evaluation_section.section_id )
        join users on ( users.user_id = section_permissions.user_id )
        where users.user_id = '.$user['user_id'];
```

but i want it to select name from users table and then match it with `users.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for` so that it get the name of assigned_for  id name 
as before group_concat I use users.name then its working but it display the name of `users.user_id = section_permissions.user_id` but i want to display name of er_id )
            where users.user_id = '.$user['user_id'];

but i want it to select name from users table and then match it with `users.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for`
in same query because in two its not working

Comment: give alias name to users table

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
$query = 'select group_concat(DISTINCT evaluation_section. section_name) as   allowed_sections from evaluation_section 
        join section_permissions on (section_permissions.section_id = evaluation_section.section_id )
        join users u1 on ( u1.user_id = section_permissions.user_id )
        join users u2 on ( u2.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for )
        where  u1.user_id = '.$user['user_id'];
```

Since you are joining "users" table twice, you will have to provide unique alias name to both of them.

Comment: personally I prefer the long hand version `INNER JOIN users AS u1` but I'm just old school I guess....

Comment: hey Millan gupta its working thankew but i want 

 select users.f_name as assign , group_concat(DISTINCT evaluation_section. section_name) as   allowed_sections from evaluation_section 
        join section_permissions on (section_permissions.section_id = evaluation_section.section_id )
        join users u1 on ( u1.user_id = section_permissions.user_id )
        join users u2 on ( u2.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for )
        where  u1.user_id = '.$user['user_id'];
for users.f_name as assign  i used  join users u2 on ( u2.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for nt wrkng

Comment: Just try adding `Select u1.f_name as assign`, it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get as what is the problem.